# Displaying a local image in Node-RED dashboard using http endpoints

Tags: javascript, html, node-red

I need to display an image on Node-RED dashboard using http end points.
I have done the followings:

1. Kept the image in /home/pi/Pictures.
2. Edited httpStatic: '/home/pi/Pictures', in setting.js file.
3. Tried using slash "/" before image name in src in html image tag and 
    without "/" *but nothing works.*

**Here is my flow for reference:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "7b08a202.a1670c",
    "type": "http in",
    "z": "e5e5e9b.2a8cc18",
    "name": "",
    "url": "/display-image",
    "method": "get",
    "upload": false,
    "swaggerDoc": "",
    "x": 112,
    "y": 73,
    "wires": [
      [
        "35ca7d97.da9dd2"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "f8cf60ed.74b87",
    "type": "http response",
    "z": "e5e5e9b.2a8cc18",
    "name": "",
    "statusCode": "",
    "headers": {

    },
    "x": 458,
    "y": 70,
    "wires": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "35ca7d97.da9dd2",
    "type": "template",
    "z": "e5e5e9b.2a8cc18",
    "name": "SLD View",
    "field": "payload",
    "fieldType": "msg",
    "format": "handlebars",
    "syntax": "mustache",
    "template": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <body>\n        <img src=\"Barsu_SLD.png\" alt=\"Overview\" width=1000px; height=800px>\n    \n    </body>\n</html>",
    "output": "str",
    "x": 310,
    "y": 136,
    "wires": [
      [
        "f8cf60ed.74b87"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2beda89c.ca2b98",
    "type": "ui_template",
    "z": "e5e5e9b.2a8cc18",
    "group": "d9e6ccf5.f58ab",
    "name": "Display Button",
    "order": 0,
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "format": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <head>\n        <style>\n            .button {\n                background-color: #086A87;\n                border: none;\n                color: white;\n                padding: 16px 32px;\n                text-align: center;\n                text-decoration: none;\n                font-size: 16px;\n                margin: 3px 1px;\n                cursor: pointer;\n                border-radius: 4px;\n            }\n            .button_over:hover {\n                background-color: #187A97;\n                color: white;\n            }\n        </style>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        \n        <a href=\"http://127.0.0.1:1880/BARSU-SLD/\" class=\"button button_over\" target=\"_blank\" >SLD View</a>    \n        \n    </body>\n </html>",
    "storeOutMessages": false,
    "fwdInMessages": true,
    "templateScope": "local",
    "x": 112,
    "y": 195,
    "wires": [
      [

      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "d9e6ccf5.f58ab",
    "type": "ui_group",
    "z": "",
    "name": "Test",
    "tab": "1474e3ec.fb238c",
    "disp": true,
    "width": "6"
  },
  {
    "id": "1474e3ec.fb238c",
    "type": "ui_tab",
    "z": "",
    "name": "Home",
    "icon": "dashboard"
  }
]
```

Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly does not work?

Comment: I am not able to display the image I have used in the template ( Barsu_SLD.png). Can you tell me where i have to put the image so that i will be able to display it on the dashboard?

Comment: If you have your `httpStatic` path set up correctly, then your node-red server can serve the image file using the url `http://localhost:1880/Barsu_SLD.png` (assuming you are using the same host and default port). Please show us the initial lines from the node-red console log after a restart...

Answer (score 1):

If you have `httpStatic` set to `~/.node-red/public`, for example using the following in `settings.js`

```
httpStatic: path.join('', 'public'),
```

and if you have a file: `~/.node-red/public/images/myimage.png`

Then your url should use the html

```
<img src="/images/myimage.png">
```

Note the initial `/` and the lack of any `http://localhost:1880`. You don't need to supply the http part since your browser will automatically match that up for you.

Just note also that if you have set `httpRoot` to something, you need to prefix your URL's with that as well.